# **kwargs не работает с форматированием строк в Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

недавно начал изучать Python 3 и столкнулся с такой проблемой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если присвоить значаение (kwargs['color']) к какой-либо переменной, то все рабоает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же если использовать старый метод форматирования строк, то тоже работает:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотелось бы узнать, почему так происходит и как это работает. Это мой первый вопрос на каком-либо форуме,
прошу сильно не критиковать в постановке вопроса, надеюсь получить ответ и полезный опыт для будущих свершений))

Comment: Текстовую информацию в вопросах лучше приводить как текст, а не как скриншоты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Не правильное выделение в кавычки*

нужно так:

```
# Одинарные кавычки в двойных или наоборот " '' "
# Одинарные  или двойные кавычки в тройных """ '' """ или """ "" """

alphavit = {"1": "A", "2": "B"}
def main():
    for key, value in alphavit.items():
        string = f"Key {key}: Value {value}"
        print(f"Key {key}: Value {value}")
    print(f"Key {key}: Value {alphavit['2']}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[Форматирование строк в Python3 PEP498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

Comment: Большое спасибо) Все заработало, вы были правы, если изменить ковычки в "kwargs['color']" на двойные, то все прекрасно работает!

Comment: А что Sublime не подсвечивает невалидный синтаксис?

Comment: Обычно подсвечивает, но здесь почему-то не сработал(

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Большое спасибо пользователю Александр'у, ваше решение помогло и спасибо за совет, впредь буду печатать код через соответствующий инструмент! ("Пример кода - {}")

Answer (score -1):

`* arg` - массив

`** kwargs` - словарь

Советую попробовать

```
def printPetNames(**pets):
   for pet,name in pets.items():
      print(f"{pet}: {name}")
```

`printPetNames(dog="Brock", fish=["Larry", "Curly", "Moe"], turtle="Shelldon")`

Comment: Дело в том, что я не понимаю почему "kwarg['color]" не работает с новым форматированием строк. Но все равно спасибо за ответ)